# How to provide ChildViewModel with data from MainViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Often when I’m designing an MVVM application, the following scenario comes up. A Window, having multiple children, sharing the same data source.

I’m trying to decide on the best way to implement a single datasource for all children. There are 3 options I can think of, all with their own advantages and disadvantages.

#### Example

The Window has two child UserControls, each in their own tab.

[image: Main Window Example]

UI is linked up like this.

[image: XAML Design]

In order to keep modularity and provide them with data, the same design is reflected in ViewModels.

[image: ViewModel Design]

The MainViewModel is set up like this.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ChildViewModelA _childViewModelA = new ChildViewModelA();
    private readonly ChildViewModelB _childViewModelB = new ChildViewModelB();

    public ChildViewModelA ChildViewModelA { get { return this._childViewModelA; } }
    public ChildViewModelB ChildViewModelB { get { return this._childViewModelB; } }
}
```

The MainWindow instantiates the MainViewModel and sets DataContext of the children. Child controls are bound to data properties.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get { return this._viewModel; } }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.View.Controls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
            <controls:ChildViewA DataContext="{Binding ViewModel.ChildViewModelA}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
            <controls:ChildViewB DataContext="{Binding ViewModel.ChildViewModelB}"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

To prevent every ViewModel from retrieving the same data from the database, I want to load data in the MainViewModel and provide the children. However, there are multiple ways of doing this.

#### Example 1: Using a setter method on the children

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...
    private readonly FakeDataManager _fakeDataManager = new FakeDataManager();
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.CurrentPerson = _fakeDataManager.GetNextPerson();
    }

    private Person _currentPerson;

    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get { return this._currentPerson; }
        set
        {
            this._currentPerson = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPerson");

            this.ChildViewModelA.SetPerson(this.CurrentPerson);
            this.ChildViewModelB.SetPerson(this.CurrentPerson);
        }
    }


public class ChildViewModelA : ViewModelBase
{
    private Person _currentPerson;

    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get { return this._currentPerson; }
        set
        {
            this._currentPerson = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPerson");
        }
    }
}
```

Easy to implement, however quickly get's hard to remain. Not a lot of code reuse. No loose coupling. Should not use this.

#### Example 2: Putting data in a container

```
public class MainViewDataContainer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _currentPerson;

    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get { return this._currentPerson; }
        set
        {
            this._currentPerson = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPerson");
        }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...
    private readonly FakeDataManager _fakeDataManager = new FakeDataManager();
    private readonly MainViewDataContainer _dataContainer = new MainViewDataContainer();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this._childViewModelA = new ChildViewModelA(_dataContainer);
        this._childViewModelB = new ChildViewModelB(_dataContainer);

        this._dataContainer.CurrentPerson = _fakeDataManager.GetNextPerson();
    }

public class ChildViewModelA : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly MainViewDataContainer _dataContainer;

    public ChildViewModelA(MainViewDataContainer dataContainer)
    {
        this._dataContainer = dataContainer;
    }

    public MainViewDataContainer DataContainer { get { return this._dataContainer; } }
}
```

Easier to maintain, more code reuse. Looser coupling.

#### Example 3: Storing in MainViewModel Properties and provide to children through an interface

```
public interface IMainDataProvider
{
    Person CurrentPerson { get; }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMainDataProvider
{
    private readonly ChildViewModelA _childViewModelA;
    private readonly ChildViewModelB _childViewModelB;

    private readonly FakeDataManager _fakeDataManager = new FakeDataManager();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this._childViewModelA = new ChildViewModelA(this);
        this._childViewModelB = new ChildViewModelB(this);

        this.CurrentPerson = _fakeDataManager.GetNextPerson();
    }

    private Person _currentPerson;

    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get { return this._currentPerson; }
        set
        {
            this._currentPerson = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPerson");
        }
    }
}

public class ChildViewModelA : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IMainDataProvider _dataProvider;

    public ChildViewModelA(IMainDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        this._dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public IMainDataProvider DataProvider { get { return this._dataProvider; } }
}
```

Yet again easier to maintain, more code reuse. Loose coupling.

Example 3 seems to be the best solution, however is this true? How do you think about this? Are there better ways to solve this issue?

Comment: I am by no means an expert, but I have to wonder: In 3), why let MainViewModel implement IDataProvider and pass it to the ChildViewModels? Why not make a class exclusively for providing data, e.g. ViewModelDataProvider?

Comment: You mean like in Example 2? That's the other option that is tempting to me. Result seems to be the same like example 3 however at cost of another class, property to store it in etc.

Comment: Yes. However, i would stil add an Interface which will be implemented by MainViewDataContainer and hand that to the child classes... doesnt get much more reuseable than that I think. I would not pass the MainViewModel to the child classes because that is not its purpose. The MainViewModel is not a data container, and later on, you will pass much more data to ChildViewModels than those actually need.
Great question by the way!

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps grouping by purpose is the right motivation to go for that option and with an added interface loose coupling is achieved. Also, I could implement a reload method in the data provider, allowing the children to call it. Just wondering if there is any future requirement that makes me wish I had provided the mainviewmodel through an interface. E.g. a non-data related method in main that needs to be called by child. Subscribing the mainviewmodel to child events would link it. If I published through an interface I could just add it. Maybe this shouldn't occur in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `CurrentPerson` is used by both ChildViewModels and `MainView` is the one who can change the CurrentPerson. How I will proceed to solve this problem is:

1. Define one base VM `ChildViewModelBase : ViewModelBase` with `CurrentPerson` property (with INotifyPropertyChanged and all). All of my `ChildViewModels` will extend this VM.
2. Use Event Aggregator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx. Using `EventAggregator` you can subscribe to `CurrentPersonChanged` event in your `ChildViewModelBase`.
3. From you `MainViewModel` once the `CurrentPerson` is loaded from db, raise `CurrentPersonChanged` event with new Person as event arguement.
4. In event handler in the `ChildViewModelBase`, set `CurrentPerson` that you get as event argument.

In this way it would not matter to your `ChildViewModels`  who is loading the `Person` from DB. Today it is `MainView`, tommorow it can be some other View also. You will just need to raise the above event with the person object as argument and Child Views will get it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to require more plumbing then the before mentioned options. The question is, do the advantages weigh up against the added complexity? Wondering how other users think about this.

Comment: You are right. It does require bit of framework code to write to create this but it is not an overhead. EventAggregator is the powerful tool which is being used in many wpf apps. Just think how much flexibility and ease it gives.. tommorow if I need to add one more child view, my mainviewmodel will not care how many childviewmodels it has, it will just publish the event and rest assure all the childs will be updated...

Comment: If I decide to introduce dependency injection in my app, then I wont be creating objects of child view models myself in mainviewmodel and update their data there.. In that case also, even IoC container will be resolving my viewmodels I will know that I have subscribed toPersonChanged event and will get updated data whenever it changes.